# Standard action bar and icons on left side

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I have a problem with standard action bar in android. I want to create bar which on the left side has: icon, icon, text, icon, and on right side: 7 icons. This is possible to do? If yes, how? I would like to hide some icons on right side if text on left is very long. Have you any advices or ideas or examples? Thank you!

Comment: Read here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html. showAsAction="ifRoom" in the XML should do the job.

Comment: yes, I tried standard action bar but in standard I can add items only from right to left, but I need add some elements on left side and some elements on right side